# Cannot select button by id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm baffled:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sendButton = $('#send');
    var name = $('#name');
}
```

is in my JavaScript file. When I open the console in Chrome, `sendButton` is not attached to anything, but `name` is attached to the `name` element.

HTML contains:

```
<input id="name"><input id="send" type="button" value="send">
```

Here's the weird part: If I type in the console:

```
> $('#send')
[<input id=​"send" type=​"button" value=​"send">]
```

So it seems that the selector is valid, but it doesn't work in the JS file, but only for the button. Any ideas?

EDIT: Sorry, I'm giving snippets here, I had the document-ready stuff.

Comment: Are you sure element '#send' is already in DOM? Are you waiting for DOM ready?

Comment: Can you build a fiddle?

Comment: [Here is a Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebC3j/) I dont understand your question.Can you elaborate a little

Comment: You are not closing your input tags?

Comment: @Nicolai The templating engine seems to be not closing them. Do you think that would be the problem?

Comment: @EricWilson try to close them. It is possible that send is inside name.

Comment: @Nicolai In HTML, the <input> tag has no end tag. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)

Comment: @Nicolai I'll try, but it seems that Jade doesn't give me the best control over them. But if that were the problem, why would I be able to get the selector to work from the console?

Comment: Ah, I guess it's not necessary for input tags :)

Comment: @captain Sorry that it is confusing to you. I can't attach anything to my `send` button. I try to assign it to a variable, and later try to use `onclick` but I can't get anywhere because the selector isn't finding the button.

Comment: Can you post `onclick` event here?

Comment: `alert($('[id=send]').length);` Gives you 0 or 1 or more?

Answer (score 1):

use `document.ready` . It might help

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// now your initialization
});
```

Comment: initially there was typo so i wrote according to that but thn question edited so i edited my answer bro

Answer (score 0):

expecting that you are searching for elements until the page is rendered.
User $(document).ready() event

Answer (score 0):

Load them after dom ready :

```
$(function() {
  var sendButton = $('#send');
  var name = $('#name');
});
```